# Accept and Store Hex values in JavaScript/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, hex

I have two questions with related to Hex values.

1. How to differentiate whether the characters are HEX format or normal text format?
2. How to accept the HEX values in JavaScript and store it in the Database?

The values will come from the Hardware device in HEX format through using TCP Ethernet.

I am using PostgreSQL to store, Table column data type is 'CHARACTER VARYING'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```js
function isHEX(s) {
    var regExp = /^[-+]?[0-9A-Fa-f]+\.?[0-9A-Fa-f]*?$/;
    return (typeof s === 'string' && regExp.test(s));
}
```